# PHP get string after a particular string in array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string something like `aa/bb/cc/dd/55/44`. Now I converted it into array using explode function.

```
explode("/","aa/bb/cc/dd/55/44");
```

Here, I want to always get the string after `dd`. String is dynamic i.e. `dd` can come in any position, but immediately after `dd` i want to get the string i.e. `55`. How can I achieve it using PHP ?

Comment: What have you tried? You can use simple `for` and check each item if it match `dd`. After that you can return `index+1`

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Therea are ways available which gets it in multiple line, but is it possible in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, for the record, if you wanted to *safely* catch **all** the occurrences of your pattern (not only just the last match), anything in between the `dd/` and the next first `/`, then you may use the following:

```
$re = "~(?<=dd/).*?(?=/)~"; 
$str = "aa/bb/cc/dd/55/44/dd/66/"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
// output: Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 66 )
```

Comment: I just want to get the first match only.

Comment: Well, then you may use: `echo isset($matches[0][0]) ? $matches[0][0] : "not found";`. (desc:  `$matches[0][0]` refers to the first occurrence, if any :)

Comment: `preg_match($re, $str, $matches);` will work ?? for only first occurrence match.

Comment: @bogojane yes, of course, in the case of `preg_match()`, just use the `$matches[0]` to refer to the  first occurrence match, if any :)

Comment: I adjusted the above code to less line. Loops may be slower to use for every occurrence.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Seriously!! lol :) you've checked against the `$v` and called **echo** in every single iteration of the loop!!

Comment: @bogojane yeah too bad you didn't say you needed one line in your questioin.   so I answered your question, got the accept, then you added some new condition to it and took the accept away.  Thats pretty lame.  I wish I never tried to help you.

Comment: Sorry, initially there was only your better solution, but @someOne actually posted the solution that i expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   $str_arr = explode("dd/","aa/bb/cc/dd/55/44");
   $str = end($str_arr);
?>
```

In $str you'll get the string part after 'dd/' i.e '55/44'. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just want to get 55 that here, not /44

Comment: <?php
   $str_arr = explode("dd/","aa/bb/cc/dd/55/44");
   $str_arr2 = explode("/",end($str_arr));
   $str = $str_arr2[0];
?>

Comment: doesn't that get the 44 ?

Comment: Try it. It'll give 55.

Comment: ah yeah i see.  i didn't see the part where you used [0] to get the first value.   Still kind of overly complicated. and 3 lines when author is insanely requiring 1 line of code for some arbitrary random unknown petty reason.

Answer (score 1):

Simple with [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$myarray = explode("/","aa/bb/cc/dd/55/44");

foreach ($myarray as $k => $v) {
      if ($v === "dd") {
          $myvalue = $myarray[$k+1];
          //break out once value is found as 
          //author requested only first result
          break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i was expecting the code which get the string after `dd` in a single line.

Comment: Need to use isset() so that it does not throw undefined index error if "dd" is at the end. `$myvalue = isset($myarray[$k+1]) ? $myarray[$k+1] : '';`

Comment: he said there would always be a value after dd

Comment: You can use `preg_match('|dd/([^/]+)/|', $str, $match);` if you are after one line answer. `$match[2]` will have the value after "dd". But yeah @NotoriousPet0 answer is better and right one.

Comment: @bogojane However, your solution will only get the **last** occurrence of  pattern matched, and also if the last characters were `/dd` then some "Undefined offset" warnings will be generated!

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
/**
 * Return string after needle if it exists.
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param mixed $needle
 * @return string
 */
function str_after($str, $needle)
{
    $pos = strpos($str, $needle);

    return ($pos !== false) ? substr($str, $pos + strlen($needle)) : $str;
}
```